# Why is MEX code much slower than the matlab code?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2012, mex, computation

**First of all, it is a request not to mark this question as duplicate as it will be clear once it is studied in detail.**

I am trying to implement Orthogonal Matching Pursuit algorithm. For that I need to find the dot product of two matrices of size 144*14596 and 144*1 as shown below

```
        clc,clear;

        load('E');
        load('R');
        load('P');


        sparse=zeros(14596,2209);

            dictionary=tem2;

            atoms=zeros(size(dictionary,1),size(dictionary,2));
            coefs=zeros(size(dictionary,2),1);
        tic
            %Normalize the dictionary 
            for index=1:size(dictionary,2)
               dictionary(:,index)=dictionary(:,index)./norm(dictionary(:,index)); 
            end
            D=dictionary;

      /*  NOTE: I tried for ii=1:5 to check the difference in computational time*/

         for ii=1:2209

            r=tem4(:,ii);
            dictionary=D;
            index=[];
            count=0;
            t=5;
            while(t>1e-15 && count~=144)
    /***************Problem lies here**************/
        % inner_product=dictionary'*r; %Dot Product (Should be slow but is fast)
        inner_product=dotProduct(dictionary',r); %(Should be fast but is very slow)
/****************************************************/
                [m,ind]=max(abs(inner_product));

                index=[index ind];
                atoms(:,ind)=dictionary(:,ind); %Select atom which has maximum inner product
                dictionary(:,ind)=0;
                at=atoms(:,index);
                x=(at'*at)\(at'*r);
                coefs(index)=x;
                r=r-at*x;
                t=norm(r);
                count=count+1;
            end
                sparse(:,ii)=coefs;

         end

        sig=D*sparse;
        final=uint8((repmat((((max(tem4))-min(tem4))./((max(sig)-min(sig)))),size(tem4,1),1).*(sig-repmat(min(sig),size(tem4,1),1)))+repmat(min(tem4),size(tem4,1),1));  

        toc
```

but the problem I am facing is that it takes a lot of time (as seen in the profiler report) in finding out the dot product using the following code in MATLAB.

> inner_product=dictionary'*r;

In order to reduce the computational time, I wrote the MEX code as shown below to find out the dot product:

```
/***********************************************************************
 *Program to create a MEX-file to find the dot product of matrices     *
 *Created by: Navdeep Singh                                            * 
 *@Copyright Reserved                                                  * 
 ***********************************************************************/

#include "mex.h"

void dot_prod(double *m1,double *m2, double *t,size_t M,size_t N, size_t M2,size_t N2 )
{   
    int i,j,k;
    double s;

    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {   for(k=0;k<N2;k++)
        {   s=0;
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {   s=s+*((m1+i)+(M*j))*(*(m2+(j+M2*k)));
            }
            *((t+i)+(M*k))=s;
        }
    }
}  

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{   double *mat1,*mat2,*out;
    size_t rows_mat1,cols_mat1,rows_mat2,cols_mat2;
    mat1=mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    mat2=mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    rows_mat1=mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    cols_mat1=mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    rows_mat2=mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    cols_mat2=mxGetN(prhs[1]);
    plhs[0]=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows_mat1,cols_mat2,mxREAL);
    out=mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    dot_prod(mat1,mat2,out,rows_mat1,cols_mat1,rows_mat2,cols_mat2);

}
```

But to my surprise I found out that MEX solution is much much slower than the one used in MATLAB, which defeats the ultimate purpose of MEX. To know the cause I searched a lot on internet and found some interesting facts such as :

[Matlab: Does calling the same mex function repeatedly from a loop incur too much overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921705/matlab-does-calling-the-same-mex-function-repeatedly-from-a-loop-incur-too-much)

[Matlab mex-file with mexCallMATLAB is almost 300 times slower than the corresponding m-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660433/matlab-mex-file-with-mexcallmatlab-is-almost-300-times-slower-than-the-correspon)

These links suggests that overhead should not be much and if there is some it is always for the first call, as time is needed to load symbol tables etc . **-- But contrary to this I found that a lot of overhead is incurring in my code.**

Also I found out that size of arguments does not matter though number of arguments can affect the computational time but it is again minimal. One of the link also suggest that dynamically allocated memory should be freed (apart from the one allocated by matlab itself) but I don't have any such kind of allocation also.

So kindly let me know what is the reason behind

**why MEX is taking huge amount of time?**

**What can be the solution to it?**

Your help is really appreciated.

Various files can be found here:

[dictionary.m](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZdi6GKYnJwlFtlK2w)

[dotProduct.c](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZdjetPRcBlLi1TEjw)

[Report MEX](https://1drv.ms/b/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZdk48_qntsHa2BRCw)

[E.mat](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZdlD_d_t8aMRzilEQ)

[R.mat](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZdnuTSbJE1kbO_oVA)

[P.mat](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArfYMunvE-HGgZdmKmYDfmV05fuOBQ)

Comment: Its almost impossible for you to write a faster code for dot product than MATLAB's. The line you say its slow, is it because  single call is slow, or because you call it so many times that it is a big percentage of the total? Also, mex files are fast, but there may be overheard in creating and passing variables

Comment: I think you have not completely read the post and your answer is unclear.

Comment: You should focus on making your MATLAB code faster rather than writing MEX code.  Matrix multiplication and dot product in MATLAB is much faster than if you were to write this on your own.  I can see several points in your MATLAB code that can be vectorized.

Comment: @Navdeep You have not shown the profiler report without the mex file.  MATLAB has probably the fastest matrix operations known to humans in 2017, my comment still holds: what makes you think you can make them faster?

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks. You are always helpful. It is ok that Matlab is faster in matrix multiplication and dot product then why is the code so slow because it takes approximately 12 mins to run this code on matlab. Also please give me some hint about which are the points that can be vectorized as most of the time is used in finding the dot product. My last question is then what is the need of MEX and where is it used, if MATLAB is faster in matrix operations.  Thanks.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I meant to say that you interpreted me wrong. I never meant to say that my code is faster. I just said that MATLAB was taking a lot of time to find dot product and to find a solution to that I searched internet and found that if I write code in MEX it will execute faster than MATLAB. So I built the code in MEX but it is of no use. Can you please provide the solution to my problem or advise me about what can be done? Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab has highly optimized code to calculate dot product of to matrices,

you just wrote a nested for loop to calculate the dot product , so you could compare this Mex code just with "similar nested for loops" in matlab then decide whether MEX code is faster or matlab ,

in fact matlab does not use nested for loop to calculate dot product of matrices,

from MATLAB doc:

> MEX-Files have several applications:
>
> - calling large pre-existing c/c++ and FORTRAN programs from MATLAB without rewriting them as MATLAB functions
> - Replacing performance-critical routines with c/c++ implementations
>
> MEX files are not appropriate for all applications. MATLAB is a high-productivity environment whose specialty is eliminating time-consuming, low-level programming in compiled languages like C or C++. In general, do your programming in MATLAB. Do not use MEX files unless your application requires it.

[EXAMPLE1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52417-fast-gaussian-point-spread-function-fitting--mex-)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell where can we use MEX. I am very much confused now.

Comment: @Navdeep you could use MEX file for example for a highly time consuming for loop, but in case of things like matrix multiplication matlab is fast enough (because of its optimized algorithm )